# Need help converting c# encryption to java (android) encryption for cross compatibility

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, cross-platform

I've been attempting to convert this class (been using it in my c# app for a couple years now) to java for use in an android application: https://gist.github.com/jbtule/4336842#file-aesthenhmac-cs

Some areas where I am having trouble is things like MemoryStream, CryptoStream, and more specifically:

```
//C# CODE
//Grab IV from message
var iv = new byte[ivLength];
Array.Copy(encryptedMessage, nonSecretPayloadLength, iv, 0, iv.Length);

using (var decrypter = aes.CreateDecryptor(cryptKey, iv))
using (var plainTextStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var decrypterStream = new CryptoStream(plainTextStream, decrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(decrypterStream))
    {
        //Decrypt Cipher Text from Message
        binaryWriter.Write(
            encryptedMessage,
            nonSecretPayloadLength + iv.Length,
            encryptedMessage.Length - nonSecretPayloadLength - iv.Length - sentTag.Length
        );
    }
    //Return Plain Text
    return plainTextStream.ToArray();
}
```

I am not quite sure what the java equivalent to CryptoStream or MemoryStream.

What I've got so far (pertaining to this code example, not the whole class)

```
//Grab IV from message
byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, nonSecretPayloadLength, iv, 0, iv.length);

Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
// MISSING: create IvParameterSpec
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
iv = ivSpec.getIV();

aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivSpec);

//byte[] decoded = aes.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedMessage));

ByteArrayOutputStream decrypterStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream binaryWriter = new DataOutputStream(decrypterStream);

        binaryWriter.write(
                encryptedMessage,
                nonSecretPayloadLength + iv.length,
                encryptedMessage.length - nonSecretPayloadLength - iv.length - sentTag.length
        );
```

If anyone could give me some pointers/help id be most grateful.

Comment: CryptoStream equivalent should be [`CipherOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) - `MemoryStream` is `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation I came up with for this code:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream plainTextStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) 
{
    // -- c# like CryptoStream
    try (CipherOutputStream decrypterStream = 
             new CipherOutputStream(plainTextStream, cipher)) 
    {
        // -- binaryWriter like c#
        try (DataOutputStream binaryWriter = new DataOutputStream(decrypterStream)) 
        {
            // -- Encrypt Data
            //Decrypt Cipher Text from Message
            binaryWriter.write(encryptedMessage,
                               nonSecretPayloadLength + iv.length,
                               encryptedMessage.length 
                                 - nonSecretPayloadLength 
                                 - iv.length 
                                 - sentTag.length);
        }

        //Return Plain Text
        //decrypterStream.flush();

    } finally {
        return plainTextStream.toByteArray();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```